# complex integral of 1/z independent of choice of ellipse?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, homotopy-theory

Can Someone please help me with the following.

complex integral of 1/z over an ellipse is independent of choice of ellipse centered at zero.

Why is this the case. Is it due to homotopy invariance, if so how?

Comment: An integral around a closed loop only depends on the residues inside.  Does that help?  In other words there's nothing special about it being an ellipse except that it is a closed loop.

Comment: yeah it does but is there any way to use the fact that this ellipse is homotopic to a circle. or is it true that an ellipse is homotopic to circle

Comment: In fact, any loop surrending 0 in the complex plane will be homotopic to each other in $\mathbb{C} \backslash 0$, implying that the integral of $\frac{1}{z}$ over any such closed curve will give you the same result

Comment: does homotopy not require same endpoint?

Comment: @george You ask a good question.  The point is that the integral around a closed loop does not depend on the endpoint, so you can use the same endpoint for both.

Answer (score 1):

For every curve surrounding the pole of the function ($0$) exactly once, the complex integral over this curve is equal to the so-called residue.

Every ellipse around the origin has this property.

Comment: To be clear, this requires that all the curves in consideration have the same winding number w.r.t. the origin (informally, that they wrap around the origin a certain number of times in a given direction).